# JavaScript Parsing: JSON to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am fairly new to JavaScript and I am a little confused with what to do with an object like the one below. How can I convert this to an array pt where each entry has the properties selid x,y,z?

this is what I see in the Chrome console:
 `Object {pt[2][y]: "1.3571934700012207", pt[0][selid]: "2", pt[0][z]: "0", pt[3][x]: "3.6684491634368896", pt[2][z]: "0"…}`

If I am trying to access pt like in the example below :

```
var X = pt[2].x;
```

I get and error "Cannot read property of undefined". I assume that this is because the object is more like a dictionary with "pt[2][y]" as key and "1.3571934700012207" as value.
However I want to access it like an array pt with objects that have the property x,y,z, selid.
Is there a way to convert/parse the data into the format I want?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You've tagged the question JSON but there's no JSON in the question. Is the text you've quoted literally the text you need to convert?

Comment: Is the code you posted what you have or what you want to get? Where is the data coming from? If you are more specific about your problem, you will get more helpful answers.

Comment: I guess pt is already an array of objects with the properties seild, x,y,z

Comment: I have updated my question - hope it makes it more clear

Comment: *"this is what I see in the Chrome console"* When you dump out *what*?

Comment: when I log with: console.log(data); data is what contains the above object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have say in comment that you do `console.log(data)` to get obj content. So probably you should do

```
var X = data["pt[2][x]"];
```

If you want to convert it into array pt you should do:

```
var data = {
    "pt[0][x]" : 1, 
    "pt[1][x]" : 2, 
    "pt[2][y]" : 3, 
    "pt[2][z]" : 3
};

var pattern = /^pt\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]$/i ;

var pt = [];
for( var key in data ){

    if ( pattern.test(key) ){
        var m = key.match(pattern);
        if( !pt[m[1]] ) pt[m[1]] = {};
        pt[m[1]][m[2]] = data[key];
    }
 }

alert(pt[0].x)
```

Comment: yes - but I need the data to be structured like an array. In further functions I have to access like that: var X = pt[2].x;  I am looking for an easy way to convert data...

Comment: I added the example of converting

Comment: Hi - thanks that worked - could you explain how the pattern var works?

Comment: This is a very long discussion. pattern is Regular expression that describe what kind of strings we want. This pattern say that we want strings that begins with pt then [ then more then one symbol that aren't ] then ] and then one more time, $ is end of line. There are 2 functions for working with regular expressions: test - check that our string is in language that create pattern. match - will parse string into array 0 element is whole string, 1 parametr is all symbols in first () and 2 in second. You can read more here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 1):

This is horribly unreadable, so I apologize for that.

But you could try this:

```
var v = {pt:new Array()};
for(var a in data) eval("if(!v." + /pt\[\d+\]/.exec(a) + ") v." + /pt\[\d+\]/.exec(a) + " = {}; v." + a.replace(/\]\[/,"][\"").replace(/\]$/,"\"]") + " = " + data[a]);
```

then v should have what you want.

(it's just creating/executing the following lines of code:

```
if(!v.pt[2]) v.pt[2] = {}; v.pt[2]["y"] = 1.3571934700012207
if(!v.pt[0]) v.pt[0] = {}; v.pt[0]["selid"] = 2
if(!v.pt[0]) v.pt[0] = {}; v.pt[0]["z"] = 0
if(!v.pt[3]) v.pt[3] = {}; v.pt[3]["x"] = 3.6684491634368896
if(!v.pt[2]) v.pt[2] = {}; v.pt[2]["z"] = 0
```

)

Answer (score 0):

the answer was already selected but here is a JSON notation for the original requested format

```
var pt=[
  {x:0,y:1,z:2,strid:"string"},
  {x:5,y:5,z:5,strid:"string2"}
];
```

so now you can do your loops like:

```
for(i=0;i<pt.length,i++){
  alert("x is:"+pt[i].x+" y is:"+pt[i].y+
       " z is:"+pt[i].z+" strid is:"+pt[i+].strid)
}
```